# Signing using iText, Adobe Reader reports "Signature was created using Not available."

Tags: java, pdf, digital-signature, digital-certificate, itext7

I am successfully signing documents using iText. However, any time that I check the "Advanced Signature Properties" in Adobe Reader I see that the "Signature was created using Not available."

[image: Signature Details]

My question is, how can I use iText update this piece of information to then display properly in Adobe Reader or any other PDF reader?

EDIT #1:

An answer suggested using the `PdfSignatureAppearance` class's `setSignatureCreator(String signatureCreator)` ([API](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/7.0.0/) and [Source](https://github.com/itext/itext7/blob/develop/sign/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/signatures/PdfSignatureAppearance.java#L381-L389)). This was not successful in updating the Signature Details in Adobe Reader. The result is the same as the screenshot included above.

Here is the exact code:

`signer.getSignatureAppearance().setSignatureCreator("iText 7.0.2");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the signature creator using the `SignatureAppearance.setSignatureCreator(String signatureCreator)` method. You can get the `SignatureAppearance`of the signature by using `signatureAppearance = pdfSigner.getSignatureAppearance()`, with `pdfSigner` the `PdfSigner`object used to create the signature in question.

Comment: This has not worked for me. I have attempted this setter method previously with no luck. Read my edits above for more details.

Comment: Hi Josh,
There was a bug regarding this that I fixed some time ago (March apparently), the fix will be included in the next release, and here's the relevant commit: https://github.com/itext/itext7/commit/8a96189b07fdae631fa8c5357560915aab7e7f16

Comment: Thanks! When can that release be expected?

Comment: Roughly a month max I think, we need to wrap up some crucial tickets in this and maybe next sprint before release.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference (and for people using different libraries like PdfBox or older *Text versions). Adobe is using the `Prop_Build` dictionary for this. The `App` dictionary defines the  following two attributes, which are concatenated:

- `Name` (e.g. "Adobe Acrobat Reader DC")
- `REx`(e.g. "2017.009.20044")

More infos about the "Digital Signature Build Dictionary Specification" are strangely defined in a [separate document](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/Acrobat_Signature_BuildDict.pdf).

Comment: I am not sure what this means. Are you saying there is a way to manually update the `Prop_Build` dictionary? I am still pretty new to iText.

Comment: Yes if you use some older iText Version or there is a bug (like mentioned in the comments above) you can manually add/change this dictionary. So you don't need to wait...